# HighChart Line Graph not Showing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using data from a csv file to generate a line graph using Highchart. Here is my code:

```
            /* Define Initial and basic Options */
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                    renderTo: 'graph_container'
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'FanniemaeAcquisition Cash Flow'
                },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount($)'
                    }
                },
                series: []
           };

            /* Parse CSV File */

            $.get('{% static "data/FanniemaeAcquisitions.csv" %}', function(csv) {
                var lines = csv.split('\n');
                var series = {
                    name: '',
                    data: []
                };
                $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
                    var items = line.split(',');

                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                        if(itemNo == 1){
                            if (lineNo == 0){
                                series.name = item;
                            } else {
                                series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
                options.series.push(series);
                console.log(options.series);
            });
            // Create the chart
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

However this isn't working. I tried testing it by manually inputting data like so:

```
                 series: [{
                     name: 'Installation',
                     data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
                 },
```

and that works fine. So I took a look at the variables being passed to `series`. The one that works(manual input):

[image]

The one that doesn't work(From CSV):

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT: Okay. something weird is going on here. Highchart isn't showing on the webpage but it showing when I download as PNG. The weirder part is that it shows on the webpage if I MANUALLY add in number values but when I extract the values form CSV the graph disappears... But when I download as PNG it shows the graph...Any ideas??

SECOND EDIT: Okay, so when I do: `console.log(JSON.stringify(options.series[0].data));`
 nothing shows up. This would mean that the values parsed from the csv file appear after the graph is generated. So how do I fix this? lol

Comment: Perhaps if you copied the output of `console.log(options.series);` here we could help, Or atleast a shortened version of it.

Comment: I did, it's the pictures

Comment: Can't see the values or the csv column, so perhaps your values are parsed incorrectly?

Comment: @anderish adding picture is not enough .add output of `console.log(options.series);` as enjoylife said

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to Javascript's Asynchronous Issues. I simply wrapped my function in a `$.when` and it worked!

Comment: Or simply move creation of the chart inside the $get() function: http://jsfiddle.net/7usk96yg/.